# Specifying height for vertical splits in vim

Tags: vim, split, buffer

Usually I am editing two files, A and B, split horizontally. I set it up, so that one buffer would only occupy the first 2 lines at the top of the screen, and the rest is for the other buffer.

Sometimes I need to edit a third file, C, which is to have half the screen realestate of the big buffer, split vertically. The following roughly shows what I would like to end up with.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| First  line of file A                                                      |
| Second line of file A                                                      |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| First  line of file C               | First  line of file B                |
| Second line of file C               | Second line of file B                |
|        ...                          |       ...                            |
| Last   line of file C               | Last   line of file B                |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The problem is, that when I do `:vsplit C` to split half of the big buffer off for the new file, vim also resizes the buffer showing file A to eat up half the screen and files B and C each get a quater screen.

How do I tell vim to not care about horizontal resizing when doing vertical splits?

**EDIT**
To be more explicit: I am looking to specify the resulting height of a buffer, when doing a vertical split. The `vsplit` command accepts only width as a parameter, not height.

I can resize windows after opening the new file, but that is rather tedious. The problem becomes more difficult with more open files. I could just stick to editing one file at a time, but I think vim is more powerful than that.

Comment: what about 30 ctrl+w- (30 is the Number of lines you want to reduce then ctrl and minus ctrl+w- )???

Comment: The answer is given on stackoverflow, here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368690/how-to-increase-the-vertical-split-window-size-in-vim

Comment: @UVV no its not. I know how to supply the width for vertical splits and the height for horitonzal splits. I am asking for height for vertical splits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn that default behavior off via

```
:set noequalalways
```

You then have to explicitly make windows equal size (e.g. with `<C-w>=`)

Alternatively, you can just turn this off for the window height via

```
:set eadirection=hor
```

Comment: `:set noequalalways` is exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

`30 ctrl-w+`  - increase window size by 30 lines

`30 ctrl-w-`       - decrease window size by 30 lines

Comment: Yes, I know that. I've just grown a little tired of having to do to things for one action.